# Displaying Excel file in a page using basic coding and iframe

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have this code below but it seem that page is not displaying the excel file to be part of the page.

```
<html>
<head>    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<object  width="900px" height="500px" id="excel"  data="C:/Users/249270/Box/SMEA/Tools/Start and Stop With Clear and Copy and Paste (2).xlsx" classid="clsid:0002E55a-0000-0000-C000-000000000046" VIEWASTEXT  >
<param name="DisplayTitleBar" value="true" />
<param name="DataType" value="CSVURL"/>
<param name="AutoFit" value="0"/>
<param name="DisplayColHeaders" value="1"/>
<param name="DisplayGridlines" value="1"/>
<param name="DisplayHorizontalScrollBar" value="1"/>
<param name="DisplayRowHeaders" value="1"/>
<param name="DisplayTitleBar" value="1"/>
<param name="DisplayToolbar" value="1"/>
<param name="DisplayVerticalScrollBar" value="1"/>
<param name="EnableAutoCalculate" value="0"/>
<param name="EnableEvents" value="0"/>
<param name="MoveAfterReturn" value="1"/>
<param name="MoveAfterReturnDirection" value="0"/>
<param name="RightToLeft" value="0"/>
</object>
<br>    <br>    <br>
<iframe src="C:/Users/249270/Box/SMEA/Tools/Start and Stop With Clear and Copy and Paste (2).xlsx" width="100%" height="500">    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect the Excel file to just display as you can't open Excel files in a browser (They need to be opened with Excel). The source of an `iframe` as designated by `src` needs to be another **HTML** file.

The only way I can think how you would be able to do this is using some JavaScript like:

```
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var excelFile = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:/Users/249270/Box/SMEA/Tools/Start and Stop With Clear and Copy and Paste (2).xlsx");
var excelSheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");
```

And then display this using some combination of JavaScript and probably some table JS library. It won't be simple to do which is probably why I have never seen anyone do it.

If it is an option for you, it would probably be a lot simpler to convert your Excel file into a Google Spreadsheet which can then be shared and embedded fairly easily.

Comment: I just trying to see if this can be done to a simple page, as i dont want other people complaining if the page work slow due to data in excel.

Comment: thank you by the way for your help. Really appreciate it.